# Use of Potato semiconduter iC in data acquisition systems

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, analog, noise

I recently came across this interesting technology: http://www.potatosemi.com/

It seems that have managed to reduce the high-frequency noise using their technology. I don't know much about noise reduction or high-frequency operation but I am curious
1)Can we use these chips for data acquisition from strain gauge sensors to achieve low noise?
2)If no What are other brief uses of such technology?

Sorry, I know that it is a very broad Question but it looks very interesting tho and I am unable to understand.
Thank You

Comment: Looks like they are working on really high speed stuff - 10s of GHz.  Not so much the thing sampling from strain guages.

Comment: @JRE Where can these be used then? Microcontroller clocks and stuff?

Comment: I don't know.  Some niche market, I expect.  GHz TTL is not something you'd normally need.  Logic at those speeds is usually integrated in larger chips rather than as (relatively) primitive building blocks.

Comment: @JRE Ohh nothing of much use to me I guess! Thank you!

Comment: One of the few main uses I can think of is in stuff like extremely low quantity measurement/scientifc/...  Equipment. Where these extreme speeds are needed that can't be achieved with FPGA's, but volume is so low that custom ASIC design is too expensive.

Comment: @JorenVaes, you might want to check what FPGAs are able to do nowadays. The internal logic may not operate at 1 GHz, but that's not a problem when you have the resources to build wide parallel data paths. OTOH, I can see these chips used for some kinds of interfacing to an FPGA.

Comment: ... assuming it's all real to begin with. The whole thing looks like an elaborate joke or hoax to me, from the hopelessly primitive website (seriously, *"Potato Chips"*?!?) to the ridiculously incomplete data sheets. I took a look at their 7400 equivalent, which gave a maximum delay of 1.5 ns (no minimum), yet claimed that it could operate at 1.125 GHz. However, a footnote indicated that anything over 133 MHz required an air speed of 1 m/s (!). This really doesn't sound like something to be taken​ seriously.

Comment: @ThePhoton I meant dealing with short data or requirements for short delays or such, not so much raw processing power. I'm constantly baffled by what they fit in FPGAs (like multiple 100G trancievers? 58gbit over 2wire?)

Comment: @DaveTweed, also a whole lot of claims of "patented technology" with no actual patent numbers provided.

Comment: @DaveTweed, No, I'm wrong. Reddit [tracked down](https://www.reddit.com/r/electronics/comments/688v3m/potato_semiconductor_you_could_call_the_potato/) their patents. Looks like a sole proprietorship, explaining why I couldn't find the patents searching by assignee.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Well, that's something, I suppose. I found a Usenet archive from 2008 talking about it, so it's been around for a while. But someone pointed out that the rated propagation delay is specified with a load of just 2 pF, which means that one gate can't even  a second one and get the advertised performance.

Comment: @DaveTweed, the description of the technology on the "IP" page is pretty bogus too. But I haven't dug in to the patents.

Comment: Sounds like the WriteOnly Memory datasheet from Signetics Corporation.